# How to duplicate a data-bound function in a view element to which the un-editable script does not apply bindings?

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js

I am a beginner to knockout and I work on a platform where only the VIEWs (called Templates) are editable - ViewModels are not editable nor even readable (except for reading the minimized code in dev tools).

I am trying to move a button from one template to another. However, the button uses a data-bound function, and each template has bindings applied (using element Id) from a different ViewModel (javascript file).

See [Graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9wlx.png)

**Ideas so far**

1. ⚡ Changing target template's main div's id was a bad idea.
2. ⬜ Wrap new button in div with same id as source template?

   - SO seems to have concensus that duplicate id's are bad.
   - Would the 2 ViewModels interfere with each other? 
     If so, can the main one be "paused" or cleared only for that new element?
3. ⬜ Should I try to recreate that part of the ViewModel in a `<script>` tag within the target template?

   - This is daunting, because I don't know js and the minimized 
     file I can see in devtools is long and does not look simple.
4. Something else?

Thank you.

**EDIT:** Adding the HTML button only `<button data-bind="click: toggleResponsiveDesign">Old UI</button>`, displays a button, but clicking it does nothing. Dev tools console gives error on page load (and a `jQuery.Deferred exception` warning referencing the error):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "click: function(){return toggleResponsiveDesign }"
> Message: toggleResponsiveDesign is not defined
>
>  at click (eval at parseBindingsString (CoreApp.js?v=v2011.0.1.1:394), :3:58)
>
>  at CoreApp.js?v=v2011.0.1.1:394
>
>  at init (CoreApp.js?v=v2011.0.1.1:394)
>
>  at init (CoreApp.js?v=v2011.0.1.1:394)
>
>  at CoreApp.js?v=v2011.0.1.1:394
>
>  at Object.G (CoreApp.js?v=v2011.0.1.1:394)
>
>  at CoreApp.js?v=v2011.0.1.1:394
>
>  at Object.D (CoreApp.js?v=v2011.0.1.1:394)
>
>  at h (CoreApp.js?v=v2011.0.1.1:394)
>
>  at l (CoreApp.js?v=v2011.0.1.1:394)

Comment: did you try just moving the button? It would be helpful to know what error you do encounter

Comment: Good point. Uncaught reference error (Unable to process binding). I added the full text at the end of my question.

Comment: is userPersonalisationApp.js loaded on the page? Then there is a chance, but you would have to show more of it

Comment: @johnSmith - when it IS loaded, the problem is - it only binds to the "userPersonalizationContainer" id (defined in UserDetailsPage.cshtml). So (idea #2 above) - if I remove that id from UserDetailsPage (source template) and add it to a div wrapped around the button in MainMenu (target template), now there are 2 .js files binding to the same thing - HeaderApp.js to the main div and UserPersonalizationApp.js to the button's div. And I get the following error: Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.

Answer (score 0):

based on your screenshots you might be able to get the clickhandler to work, as the viewmodel of Userpersonalisationapp.js is bound to variable `r` you could change your buttons databind in headerapp template to

```
<button data-bind="click: r.toggleResponsiveDesign">
```

It may be that you have to add `()` to it to make the function run as it is not applied to header template

```
<button data-bind="click: r.toggleResponsiveDesign()">
```

I would give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done. If your graphic is accurate, you're working with two totally separate viewmodels that aren't in any way connected or aware of each other. If the viewmodels were nested, accessing one from the other would be pretty trivial, but that appears not to be the case here.

This is what [components](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html) are for, actually. Usually you'd call `applyBindings` *once* for your entire application, and the rest would be divided into components, which gives you a way of sharing data and methods between them. The way your app is structured right now, you just can't do that. That, and your apparent inability to edit or even get a good look the viewmodels really puzzles me. Whoever though *that* was a good idea?

Comment: I will learn about components - thank you!! Would it be (theoretically) possible to copy the relevant part from the original ViewModel (UserPersonalizationApp.js) and paste it into the target View (MainMenu.cshtml) - for example, into a <script> tag right above my button? If so, how would I bind it to the button without conflicting with the overall ViewModel (HeaderApp.js) binding?